# Mysql Database TDE Encryption through xampp?

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption, mysql-workbench, tde

I have been trying to figure out how to transparent data encryption my Mysql Database for weeks. Time is running out. I need help.. I am using xampp and possibly going to turn to Postgres.

If TDE is not possible for xampp mysql, then is there a way to lock the database say if I were to connect through MySQL Workbench, it will show error or prompt for password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MySQL does not suport TDE. You have to do encryption in your application.

Comment: So the only way is to use AES encryption?

Comment: You can use whatever encryption you want. You only have to implement it yourself (e.g. encrypt data before writing to the db).

Comment: Oracle has added TDE support to MySQL Enterprise Edition... https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html

Comment: Downvoter: please consider when I wrote this answer. You cannot downvote an old answer just because it's no longer true after years.